# HTML5 input pattern - exactly 'N' quantity of numbers

Tags: html, html-input

I want an input that it can only enter exactly N quantity of numbers , no less, no more.

I have tried this:
Example with 4 digits.

```
<input type="text" name="myinput" pattern="[0-9]{4}" title="Only four (4) digits.">
```

But it does not work, someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Do you need maxlength attribute like this: `<input type="text" name="myinput" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" title="Only four (4) digits.">`
?

Comment: @cristian I also need minlength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "it does not work" I assume you mean the pattern isn't checked when the input is empty. Otherwise there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the pattern.

That is how the `pattern` attribute works. You'll have to add `required` as well if you don't want to allow empty input.

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="myinput" pattern="[0-9]{4}" required>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```